# Detecting Cell Click On A Table Row That Is Already Selected

Tags: java, click, jtable, selection, cell

I have a JFrame application that contains a *JTabel*. The underlying table model is my own class that I made that extends *AbstractTableModel*. The data in the first column is of type boolean and so I want it to show the value in the form of a checkbox. To do this, I added the following code in my table model *getColumnClass* method:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
        return Boolean.class;
    } else if (columnIndex == 1) {
    ....
    ....
}
```

This works fine and my table cell looks like the following which is what I want:

[image: JTable Checkbox Columns]

The behavior I now want is that when the user clicks on a cell in column 0 of any row I want to toggle the value of *On Sale*.

My main class listens to selections in the table by implementing *ListSelectionListener* and overriding the *valueChanged* method. Inside the *valueChanged* method I can check the selected column by calling *table.getSelectedColumn* and checking to see if it's 0 then getting the object at the selected row and toggling the boolean on sale value.

The problem I am running into is that if a particular row is already selected and the user clicks the cell in column 0 for the selected row the *valueChanged* method is never called and so therefore I never toggle the value.

My quesion is, how do I detect a cell selection/click on a row that is already selected? Should I use a mouse selection listener then determine the cell that was clicked using the location data from the mouse click event?

Thank you.

Comment: Get the rows which is selected and then get the row,column of the mouse click. Compare both.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listening to table change instead ? You would need to implement TableModelListener and to have this :

```
 public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
    String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
    Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);

    ...// Do something with the data...
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about that but nothing is changing in the table so when will tableChanged ever get called?

Comment: if you implement DefaultTableModel instead of AbstractTableModel, it will automatically fire a tableChanged event whenever something is updated on the table model (a cell, a row, the table structure)